# What is the standard approach to store dates as pixel values in raster?

Tags: raster, date, optimization, format, bit-depth

I have a raster, where the value of a pixel should represent the date at which that pixel was deforested. Dates ranging from 2015 until today. I need resolution to be at the level of day.
I would like to be able to perform raster maths on pixels (i.e. show all pixels between two dates), so ISO dates are not appropriate.

What format could I use for dates? I am making a code library so I want to use accepted standards where possible.

I am doing raster processing that needs to be fast (Im using Google Earth Engine JS API). So storing the full unix timestamp as pixel values seems to be overkill. But I presume it needs to be an integer.

Is there a best practice approach for this?

Comment: Perhaps Julian day then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day.

Comment: Or convert dates to POSIX integer.

Comment: I guess the kind of processing you will make on your raster should be considered (converting from a custom date format may not be optimal)

Comment: Over what time period and what level of precision (days, months, years)? What software will you use to access the values?

Comment: +1 for Julian Day. @user30184 you should add that as an answer as the ISO format answer is not very useful. Julian Day fits in the range of UInt16 (0-65,535) raster data type so would take up less space than an ISO format as well.

Comment: Time range from 2015 to present, precision is day. Thanks!

Comment: Please [Edit] the question with clarifying details.  Defining your own date datatype of days since 01-Jan-2015 (or 2010, or 2000); with day resolution, you have 175 years to pack an unsigned 16-bit int as you wish. Still, it's your call, so maybe too *opinion-based* for GIS SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best solution is to use **Unix Days** (days since epoch, 1st Jan 1970). This can be obtained by `millis_since_epoch / 8.64e7`. This means we can still use 16bit raster, whereas POSIX date or Unix Timestamp would require a 32-bit raster to store those long values. Julian day is also a good option, but I have no use for the day values between 1 January 4713 and 1 January 1970.
In the absence of an accepted standard, Unix Days is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the ISO 8601 format without the dashes, e.g. YYYYMMDD => 20220225

Comment: 20220301-20220228 is 1 day, not 73 so ISO format wouldn't be suited to all analyses.